# This is SO's css path http://sstatic.net/so/all.css?v=6184" what is this ?v=6184"?

Tags: css

This is SO's css path http://sstatic.net/so/all.css?v=6184" what is this **?v=6184"?**

What it does? if it useful then how to use this? can i use this on any site PHP, ASp.net etc

Comment: Do you want to know what it is in general or what it is used for in this very case?

Comment: @Gumbo - both what is this ? and if this useful then how to use

Comment: This question does not deserve the close votes.  Not only does it ask what the heck it does, but it also asks if it can be done on PHP and other sites, and one could reasonable assume HOW!

Comment: 2 upvotes 3 vote to close the question :) anything can be happen on SO.

Comment: Well, if you really want to know what this is used for on SO, ask someone from the SO developer team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a way to control caching. When the value of the "v" parameter changes, the browser will consider it a different URL and ask for a new copy of the file instead of using its cached copy. This technique is often used to "version" static files by providing something like a timestamp in the query string that marks when the file was last changed.

Comment: so overall it's a useful thing to have in every website

Comment: Yes, and to answer the second part of your question that you added, it has to do with the web server and the HTTP request, not which server side scripting language your site uses. It can be used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's a query string. It can be parsed by server-side processes for allowing variable parts of the stylesheet, or it can be used to disable caching by browsers or proxies.